# Output audio from mic on bluetooth headset to phone speaker

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio, audio-recording, speaker

I want to get audio from the mic on a bluetooth headset, send it to the connected phone, and play it on the phone speakers. I'm aware there are different profiles and protocols to be used, but I'm unsure on how to start. What method can I use to achieve this with minimum delay?

Context: A friend of mine works in healthcare and is shouting themself hoarse while speaking to others through the PPE. If possible, I'd like to provide them with an app that lets them use their phone speakers as a megaphone to amplify their voice  - If such an app already exists, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.